# Can't Connect Client(ReactJS) and Backend(NodeJS) both working on different Ports on the Localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I've worked with ReactJS before but this is my first time messing around with NodeJS
[This is the ReactJS code where I'm trying to send the Video File to the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v4Ee.png)

[This is the NodeJS file I'm simply trying to print something to the console but nothing works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUI26.png)

This is definitely a dumb question I know, it's just I don't know what I'm doing wrong, it's my first time messing around with Backend stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Have you added the CORS module to your backend so it accepts request from a different URL?

Install cors with 'npm install cors' then add the following to your backend server.js (or index.js or whatever file is creating the routes):

```
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';

const app = express()
app.use(cors)
```

The app.use has to come before your routes

Comment: And if this is the issue (which seems likely) it's worth to mention that CORS-errors or warnings show in the browser dev console (so you know where to look next time!)